# Bootstrap dropdown item binding with Ajax source

Tags: ajax, twitter-bootstrap, dropdownbox

I have Bootstrap dropdown button, I want get data when user click this dropdown button instead of I need load country list at page loading time, here is my code;

```
<div class="btn-group">
<input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Country field   is required." id="Country" name="Country" type="text" value="US" />
<a class="btn dropdown-toggle country" id="country" data-toggle="dropdown">
<span class="caret"></span>
</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu countrys" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
   //store country list
</ul>
</div>
```

I click dropdown button, it can't trigger jquery work, it seems Bootstrap don't allow custom dropdown function.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#country').click(function () {
            // Only call notifications when opening the dropdown
            if (!$(this).hasClass('open')) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "/getCountries",
                    async: false,
                    dataType: "script"
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Bootstrap allows almost anything you can imagine. Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: no, I use firefox set break, it seems bootstrap disable client event.

Comment: I made mistake, put this script before jquery

Comment: Ah. Glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to add the ajax request inside the dropdown-open event. something like this:

```
$('#myDropdown').on('show.bs.dropdown', function () {
  // do something…
})
```

show.bs.dropdow-- This event fires immediately when the show instance method is called. The toggling anchor element is available as the relatedTarget property of the event.